# Grouping Smaller Values in Matplotlib Pie Chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a pie chart that has too many categories that make it impossible to read. Is there a way to group the smaller values, say anything under 4% into an "Other Category?" Currently,. it's impossible to read the smaller values.

```
counts = df['Term'].value_counts()
counts.plot.pie(autopct='%.2f%%')
plt.show()
```